# How can I get the paginator to show the correct page after changing it?

Tags: angular, pagination, primeng, eventemitter

I seem to have a bug with my pagination that I can't work out. The thing is that I can change the page via the `p-paginator`from prime-ng. While doing so the content of the page changes accordingly to the request but the `pageNum`always stays at 1 even if I clicked page .

To give you some background information about my code setup: I have two components called `applicant`and  `applicant-filtered`. The `applicant-filtered` component is called from the  `applicant`component with this lines of code if a filter is setup.

```html
<dgam-applicants-filtered (pageChanged)="onPageChanged($event)"
                                      *ngIf="searchObject && applicantsSearchResponse && !isLoading"
                                      [applicantSearchObject]="searchObject"
                                      [applicantsSearchResponse]="applicantsSearchResponse">
            </dgam-applicants-filtered>
```

The filter is working perfectly fine so that is not the issue so I won't post the code for that.  But here is the code for the methode `onPageChanged`:

```js
onPageChanged(event: any) {
        this.searchObject.pageRequest.pageNum = event.page;
        this.searchApplicants();
    }
```

The `applicant-filtered`component looks like this:

```html
<ng-container *ngIf="applicantsSearchResponse?.page.content.length > 0">
    <div class="filteredApplicantCards flex flex-wrap w-100 mt2">
        <div *ngFor="let applicant of applicantsSearchResponse?.page.content"
             class="filteredApplicantCard ma2 pb3 gray shadow-1 bg-white z-0">
            <dgam-applicant-card [applicantProfile]="applicant"></dgam-applicant-card>
        </div>
    </div>
</ng-container>


<p-paginator (onPageChange)="paginate($event)"
             *ngIf="applicantsSearchResponse?.page.totalCount > applicantSearchObject.pageRequest.pageSize"
             [rows]="applicantSearchObject.pageRequest.pageSize"
             [totalRecords]="applicantsSearchResponse?.page.totalCount"
             class="custom-pagination">
</p-paginator>
```

and that's the typescript:

```js
import {Component, EventEmitter, Input, OnInit, Output} from '@angular/core';
import {ApplicantSearch, ApplicantSearchResponse} from '../interfaces/applicant';


@Component({
    selector: 'dgam-applicants-filtered',
    templateUrl: './applicants-filtered.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./applicants-filtered.component.scss']
})
export class ApplicantsFilteredComponent implements OnInit {
    @Input() applicantsSearchResponse: ApplicantSearchResponse;
    @Input() applicantSearchObject: ApplicantSearch;
    @Output() pageChanged: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();

    constructor() {
    }

    ngOnInit() {
    }

    paginate(event) {
        this.pageChanged.emit(event);
    }
}
```

There is no errors in the console and debugging hasn't bought up any insides. So I'm kinda running out of clues and ideas.

If you have any insights or ideas please let me know. I appreciate them very much to solve this problem. If you need any more code or information please tell me and i will provide it. Thanks.

EDIT: Here is the whole code of the `applicant` component:

```js
import {animate, state, style, transition, trigger} from '@angular/animations';
import {Component, ElementRef, Input, OnInit, ViewChild} from '@angular/core';
import {AbstractControl, FormBuilder, FormControl, FormGroup} from '@angular/forms';
import {Router} from '@angular/router';
import {ChangeContext, Options} from 'ng5-slider';
import {DialogService} from 'primeng/api';
import {of, timer} from 'rxjs';
import {debounce, finalize, switchMap, tap} from 'rxjs/operators';
import {CityGeo} from '../../services/city/city-interfaces';
import {ApplicantCreationDialogComponent} from './applicant-creation-dialog/applicant-creation-dialog.component';
import {
    ApplicantFilter,
    ApplicantSearch,
    ApplicantSearchResponse,
    ApplicantSortingCriteria
} from './interfaces/applicant';
import {ApplicantService} from './services/applicant.service';

@Component({
    animations: [
        trigger('FadeAnimation', [
            state('in', style({opacity: 1})),
            transition(':enter', [
                style({opacity: 0}),
                animate(400)
            ]),
            transition(':leave',
                animate(400, style({opacity: 0})))
        ])
    ],
    providers: [DialogService],
    selector: 'dgam-applicant',
    styleUrls: ['./applicant.component.scss'],
    templateUrl: './applicant.component.html'
})
export class ApplicantComponent implements OnInit {
    static ONLY_MY_APPLICANTS = 'onlyMyApplicants';
    static ONLY_MY_BRANCH = 'onlyMyBranch';
    static ONLY_MY_TENANT = 'onlyMyTenant';
    static IS_GLOBE = 'isGlobe';
    static IS_MOBILE = 'isMobile';
    static IS_SPECULATIVE_APPLICATION = 'isSpeculativeApplication';
    static IS_JOB_APPLICATION = 'isJobApplication';
    static IS_EMPLOYEE = 'isEmployee';
    static IS_APPLICANT = 'isApplicant';
    static IS_SHIFTWORK_IMAGINABLE = 'isShiftWorkImaginable';
    static AGE_REQUEST = 'ageRequest';
    static CITY_WITH_RADIUS = 'cityWithRadius';
    static CITY_WITH_ZIP_CODE = 'cityWithZipCode';
    skillsIncludeFilterValues: string[] = [];
    skillsIncludeFilterOption = 'and';
    skillsExcludeFilterValues: string[] = [];
    selectedLanguages: string[] = [];
    cityForm: FormGroup;
    cityProposals: CityGeo[] = [];
    proposalsVisible = false;
    highlightedCity: CityGeo;
    city: '';
    selectedCity: CityGeo;
    minAge = 0;
    maxAge = 100;
    options: Options = {
        ceil: 100,
        floor: 0
    };

    isLoading = true;

    @Input() showFilter: boolean;
    @Input() possibleFilters: ApplicantFilter[];
    requestFilters: ApplicantFilter[] = [];
    @ViewChild('ageSlider') ageSlider: ElementRef;

    isFiltered = false;
    // die folgenden Booleans werden nur fuer die Filterung benoetigt
    onlyMyApplicants = false;
    onlyMyBranch: false;
    onlyMyTenant: false;
    speculativeApp: false;
    jobApplication: false;
    isEmployee: false;
    isApplicant: false;
    isGlobe: false;
    isMobile: false;
    isShiftWorkImaginable: false;

    applicantsSearchResponse: ApplicantSearchResponse;

    searchObject: ApplicantSearch = {
        pageRequest: {
            pageNum: 0,
            pageSize: 16,
            sortByList: [
                {name: 'firstContactReceived', direction: 'DESCENDING'}
            ]
        }
    };

    sortingCriterias = [
        {sort: [{name: 'firstContactReceived', direction: 'ASCENDING'}], title: 'NEWEST'},
        {sort: [{name: 'firstContactReceived', direction: 'DESCENDING'}], title: 'OLDEST'}
    ];

    selectedSorting: ApplicantSortingCriteria[] = this.sortingCriterias[0].sort;


    constructor(private applicantService: ApplicantService,
                private fb: FormBuilder,
                private router: Router,
                private dialogService: DialogService) {
    }

    get radiusControl(): AbstractControl {
        return this.cityForm.get('mobility').get('jobLocationRadius');
    }

    onFilterDelete(filterToDelete: ApplicantFilter) {
        this.searchObject.requestFilters = this.searchObject.requestFilters
            .filter(requestedFilter => requestedFilter.name !== filterToDelete.name);

        if (filterToDelete.name === ApplicantComponent.ONLY_MY_APPLICANTS) {
            this.onlyMyApplicants = false;
        } else if (filterToDelete.name === ApplicantComponent.IS_GLOBE) {
            this.isGlobe = false;
        } else if (filterToDelete.name === ApplicantComponent.IS_MOBILE) {
            this.isMobile = false;
        } else if (filterToDelete.name === ApplicantComponent.ONLY_MY_TENANT) {
            this.onlyMyTenant = false;
        } else if (filterToDelete.name === ApplicantComponent.ONLY_MY_BRANCH) {
            this.onlyMyBranch = false;
        } else if (filterToDelete.name === ApplicantComponent.IS_SPECULATIVE_APPLICATION) {
            this.speculativeApp = false;
        } else if (filterToDelete.name === ApplicantComponent.IS_JOB_APPLICATION) {
            this.jobApplication = false;
        } else if (filterToDelete.name === ApplicantComponent.IS_APPLICANT) {
            this.isApplicant = false;
        } else if (filterToDelete.name === ApplicantComponent.IS_EMPLOYEE) {
            this.isEmployee = false;
        } else if (filterToDelete.name === ApplicantComponent.IS_SHIFTWORK_IMAGINABLE) {
            this.isShiftWorkImaginable = false;
        } else if (filterToDelete.name === ApplicantComponent.CITY_WITH_RADIUS ||
            filterToDelete.name === ApplicantComponent.CITY_WITH_ZIP_CODE) {
            this.cityForm.reset();
        } else if (filterToDelete.name === ApplicantComponent.AGE_REQUEST) {
            let ageFilter: ApplicantFilter = this.possibleFilters.find(filter => filter.name === ApplicantComponent.AGE_REQUEST);
            if (ageFilter) {
                ageFilter.selection = undefined;
                this.options = {
                    ceil: this.maxAge,
                    floor: this.minAge
                };
            } else {
                const newAgeFilter: ApplicantFilter = {
                    name: ApplicantComponent.AGE_REQUEST,
                    selection: [this.minAge, this.maxAge],
                    values: undefined
                };
                this.possibleFilters.push(newAgeFilter);
            }
            ageFilter = this.requestFilters.find(filter => filter.name === ApplicantComponent.AGE_REQUEST);
            if (ageFilter) {
                ageFilter.selection = [this.minAge, this.maxAge];
            } else {
                const newAgeFilter: ApplicantFilter = {
                    name: ApplicantComponent.AGE_REQUEST,
                    selection: undefined,
                    values: undefined
                };
                this.options = {
                    ceil: this.maxAge,
                    floor: this.minAge
                };
                this.requestFilters.push(newAgeFilter);
            }
        } else if (filterToDelete.name === 'skillsAnd') {
            this.skillsIncludeFilterValues = [];
            this.skillsIncludeFilterOption = 'and';
        } else if (filterToDelete.name === 'skillsOr') {
            this.skillsIncludeFilterValues = [];
            this.skillsIncludeFilterOption = 'and';
        } else if (filterToDelete.name === 'skillsNot') {
            this.skillsExcludeFilterValues = [];
        } else if (filterToDelete.name === 'languages') {
            this.selectedLanguages = [];
        }
        this.searchApplicants();
    }

    isSearchByAge(): boolean {
        const ageFilter = this.possibleFilters.find(filter => filter.name === ApplicantComponent.AGE_REQUEST);

        let isSearchByAge = false;
        if (ageFilter && ageFilter.selection) {
            isSearchByAge = ageFilter.selection[0] !== String(this.minAge) || ageFilter.selection[1] !== String(this.maxAge);
        }
        return isSearchByAge;
    }

    public searchApplicants() {

        this.isFiltered = this.isSearchByAge() || this.onlyMyApplicants || this.isGlobe || this.isMobile ||
            this.onlyMyBranch || this.onlyMyTenant || this.jobApplication ||
            this.speculativeApp || this.isEmployee || this.isApplicant || this.isShiftWorkImaginable ||
            this.searchObject.requestFilters.filter(filter =>
                this.isNotABooleanFilter(filter)
            ).some(f => f.selection !== undefined || f.selection !== null);

        this.isLoading = true;

        if (this.isFiltered) {
            this.setSelectionForAllBooleanFilter();

            // CHOOSE_SORTING nicht mitsenden
            this.searchObject.pageRequest.sortByList =
                this.searchObject.pageRequest.sortByList.filter(sorting => sorting.name);
            this.applicantService.searchApplicants(this.searchObject).pipe(
                finalize(() => this.isLoading = false)
            ).subscribe(response => {
                this.applicantsSearchResponse = response;
                this.possibleFilters = response.possibleFilters;

                const ageFilter: ApplicantFilter = response.requestedFilters.find(filter => filter.name === ApplicantComponent.AGE_REQUEST);
                if (!ageFilter) {
                    response.possibleFilters.push({
                        name: ApplicantComponent.AGE_REQUEST,
                        selection: undefined,
                        values: undefined
                    });
                }

                const cityFilter: ApplicantFilter = response.requestedFilters.find(filter => filter.name === ApplicantComponent.CITY_WITH_RADIUS);
                if (!cityFilter) {
                    response.possibleFilters.push({
                        name: ApplicantComponent.CITY_WITH_RADIUS,
                        selection: undefined,
                        values: undefined
                    });
                }
                const cityZipFilter: ApplicantFilter = response.requestedFilters.find(filter => filter.name === ApplicantComponent.CITY_WITH_ZIP_CODE);
                if (!cityZipFilter) {
                    response.possibleFilters.push({
                        name: ApplicantComponent.CITY_WITH_ZIP_CODE,
                        selection: undefined,
                        values: undefined
                    });
                }


                const nationalityFilter = this.possibleFilters.find(filter => filter.name === 'nationality');

                if (nationalityFilter) {
                    this.possibleFilters.push({
                        name: 'excludeNationality',
                        selection: undefined,
                        values: nationalityFilter.values
                    });
                }

                // bei Antwort vom Server setzen wir die Dropdowns auf die gewählten Werte,
                // somit ist das FilterPanel in dem Zustand, den wir angefragt hatten
                this.applicantsSearchResponse.requestedFilters.forEach(requestedFilter => {
                    const filter = this.possibleFilters.find(possibleFilter => possibleFilter.name === requestedFilter.name);
                    if (filter) {
                        if (filter.name === ApplicantComponent.AGE_REQUEST) {
                            filter.selection = requestedFilter.values;
                        } else if (filter.name === ApplicantComponent.CITY_WITH_RADIUS) {
                            filter.selection = requestedFilter.values;
                        } else if (filter.name === ApplicantComponent.CITY_WITH_ZIP_CODE) {
                            filter.selection = requestedFilter.values;
                        } else {
                            filter.selection = requestedFilter.values[0];
                            if (filter.name === 'excludeNationality') {
                                filter.values.push(requestedFilter.values[0]);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });
            });

        } else {
            this.fetchPossibleFilters();
        }
    }

    public changeSorting() {
        this.searchObject.pageRequest.sortByList = this.selectedSorting;
        this.searchApplicants();
    }

    public onfilterChanged(filters: ApplicantFilter[]) {
        this.searchObject.requestFilters = filters;
        this.searchObject.pageRequest.pageNum = 0;
        this.searchApplicants();
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.fetchPossibleFilters();
        this.createForm();
        this.initLocationSubscription();
        this.cityForm.get('mobility').get('jobLocationRadius').disable();
    }


    newApplicant() {
        this.dialogService.open(ApplicantCreationDialogComponent, {
            header: 'Bewerber anlegen'
        }).onClose.subscribe(applicantId => {
                if (applicantId) {
                    this.router.navigate(['applicant/edit', applicantId]);
                }
            }
        );
    }

    patchProposal(proposal: CityGeo, event: any = null): void {
        // noinspection DuplicatedCode
        if (event) {
            // when enter is pressed to use a highlightedProposal, prevent the default which would be the form submitting
            event.preventDefault();
        }
        this.selectedCity = proposal;
        (this.cityForm.get('mobility').get('city') as FormControl).patchValue(proposal.city, {emitEvent: false});
        (this.cityForm.get('mobility').get('cityGeoId') as FormControl).patchValue(proposal.id, {emitEvent: false});
        this.proposalsVisible = false;
        this.cityForm.get('mobility').get('jobLocationRadius').enable();
        const cityWithRadius = this.possibleFilters.find(filter => filter.name === ApplicantComponent.CITY_WITH_RADIUS);
        cityWithRadius.selection = [proposal.id, this.radiusControl.value, proposal.city];
    }

    highlightPreviousProposal(): void {
        const currentIndex = this.cityProposals.findIndex(proposal => proposal === this.highlightedCity);
        let newIndex = currentIndex - 1;
        if (newIndex < 0) {
            newIndex = this.cityProposals.length - 1;
        }
        this.highlightedCity = this.cityProposals[newIndex];
    }

    highlightNextProposal(): void {
        const currentIndex = this.cityProposals.findIndex(proposal => proposal === this.highlightedCity);
        let newIndex = currentIndex + 1;
        if (newIndex === this.cityProposals.length) {
            newIndex = 0;
        }
        this.highlightedCity = this.cityProposals[newIndex];
    }

    public onFilterSelection() {
        const requestFilters: ApplicantFilter[] = [];

        for (const filter of this.possibleFilters) {

            if (filter.name === ApplicantComponent.ONLY_MY_APPLICANTS) {
                filter.selection = this.onlyMyApplicants ? String(true) : undefined;
            } else if (filter.name === ApplicantComponent.IS_GLOBE) {
                filter.selection = this.isGlobe ? String(true) : undefined;
            } else if (filter.name === ApplicantComponent.IS_MOBILE) {
                filter.selection = this.isMobile ? String(true) : undefined;
            } else if (filter.name === ApplicantComponent.ONLY_MY_BRANCH) {
                filter.selection = this.onlyMyBranch ? String(true) : undefined;
            } else if (filter.name === ApplicantComponent.ONLY_MY_TENANT) {
                filter.selection = this.onlyMyTenant ? String(true) : undefined;
            } else if (filter.name === ApplicantComponent.IS_JOB_APPLICATION) {
                filter.selection = this.jobApplication ? String(true) : undefined;
            } else if (filter.name === ApplicantComponent.IS_SPECULATIVE_APPLICATION) {
                filter.selection = this.speculativeApp ? String(true) : undefined;
            } else if (filter.name === ApplicantComponent.IS_EMPLOYEE) {
                filter.selection = this.isEmployee ? String(true) : undefined;
            } else if (filter.name === ApplicantComponent.IS_APPLICANT) {
                filter.selection = this.isApplicant ? String(true) : undefined;
            } else if (filter.name === ApplicantComponent.IS_SHIFTWORK_IMAGINABLE) {
                filter.selection = this.isShiftWorkImaginable ? String(true) : undefined;
            }
            if (filter.name === ApplicantComponent.AGE_REQUEST && this.isSearchByAge()) {
                requestFilters.push({
                    name: filter.name,
                    values: [String(filter.selection[0]), String(filter.selection[1])]
                });
            } else if (filter.selection) {
                if (filter.name === ApplicantComponent.CITY_WITH_RADIUS) {
                    const values = filter.selection as string[];
                    requestFilters.push({
                        name: filter.name,
                        values: [values[0], values[1], values[2]]
                    });
                } else if (filter.name === ApplicantComponent.CITY_WITH_ZIP_CODE) {
                    const values = filter.selection as string[];
                    requestFilters.push({
                        name: filter.name,
                        values: [values[0]]
                    });
                } else {
                    requestFilters.push({
                        name: filter.name,
                        values: [filter.selection as string]
                    });
                }
            }
        }

        if (this.isSkillIncludeSearchActive()) {
            requestFilters.push({
                name: this.skillsIncludeFilterOption === 'and' ? 'skillsAnd' : 'skillsOr',
                values: this.skillsIncludeFilterValues
            });
        }

        if (this.isSkillsExcludeSearchActive()) {
            requestFilters.push({
                name: 'skillsNot',
                values: this.skillsExcludeFilterValues
            });
        }

        if (this.isLanguageSearchActive()) {
            requestFilters.push({
                name: 'languages',
                values: this.selectedLanguages
            });
        }

        this.onfilterChanged(requestFilters);
    }

    getChipText(filter: ApplicantFilter): string {
        if (filter.name === ApplicantComponent.ONLY_MY_APPLICANTS) {
            return 'Meine Bewerber';
        } else if (filter.name === ApplicantComponent.IS_GLOBE) {
            return 'Reisebereitschaft';
        } else if (filter.name === ApplicantComponent.IS_MOBILE) {
            return 'Mobilität';
        } else if (filter.name === ApplicantComponent.IS_SHIFTWORK_IMAGINABLE) {
            return 'Schichtarbeit';
        } else if (filter.name === ApplicantComponent.ONLY_MY_BRANCH) {
            return 'Meine Geschäftsstelle';
        } else if (filter.name === ApplicantComponent.ONLY_MY_TENANT) {
            return 'Meine Firma';
        } else if (filter.name === ApplicantComponent.IS_SPECULATIVE_APPLICATION) {
            return 'Initiativbewerbung';
        } else if (filter.name === ApplicantComponent.IS_JOB_APPLICATION) {
            return 'Stellenbewerbung';
        } else if (filter.name === ApplicantComponent.AGE_REQUEST) {
            return `Alter ${filter.values[0]}-${filter.values[1]}`;
        } else if (filter.name === ApplicantComponent.CITY_WITH_RADIUS) {
            return `Wunschort: ${filter.values[1]}km um ${filter.values[2]}`;
        } else if (filter.name === ApplicantComponent.CITY_WITH_ZIP_CODE) {
            return `Wunschort nach PLZ: ${filter.values[0]}`;
        } else if (filter.name === 'skillsAnd') {
            return this.skillsIncludeFilterValues.join(' & ');
        } else if (filter.name === 'skillsOr') {
            return this.skillsIncludeFilterValues.join(' ODER ');
        } else if (filter.name === 'skillsNot') {
            return `NICHT ${this.skillsExcludeFilterValues.join(' ODER ')}`;
        } else if (filter.name === 'languages') {
            return this.selectedLanguages.join(', ');
        } else if (filter.name === 'status') {
            const filterName = filter.values + '';
            if (filterName === 'NEW') {
                return 'Neu';
            } else if (filterName === 'DECLINED') {
                return 'Abgelehnt';
            } else if (filterName === 'IN_WORK') {
                return 'Angestellt';
            } else if (filterName === 'IN_DEALING_WITH') {
                return 'in Bearbeitung';
            }
        } else if (filter.name === 'applicantStatus') {
            const filterName = filter.values + '';
            if (filterName === 'EMPLOYEE') {
                return 'Mitarbeiter(in)';
            } else if (filterName === 'APPLICANT') {
                return 'Bewerber(in)';
            }
        } else if (filter.name === 'state') {
            const filterName = filter.values + '';
            return filterName === 'reserved' ? 'Reserviert' : 'Angefragt';
        } else if (filter.name === 'excludeNationality') {
            return filter.values + ' ausschließend';
        } else {
            return typeof filter.values === 'string' ? filter.values : filter.values[0];
        }
    }

    onPageChanged(event: any) {
        this.searchObject.pageRequest.pageNum = event.page;
        this.searchApplicants();
    }

    onFilterStatus(status: string) {
        const requestFilters: ApplicantFilter[] = [];
        if (status === 'RESERVED' || status === 'REQUESTED') {
            if (status === 'RESERVED') {
                requestFilters.push({
                    name: 'state',
                    values: ['reserved']
                });
            } else {
                requestFilters.push({
                    name: 'state',
                    values: ['questioned']
                });
            }
        } else {
            requestFilters.push({
                name: 'status',
                values: [status]
            });
        }

        this.onfilterChanged(requestFilters);
    }

    onAgeChanged(changeContext: ChangeContext) {
        const ageFilter = this.possibleFilters.find(filter => filter.name === ApplicantComponent.AGE_REQUEST);
        ageFilter.selection = [changeContext.value, changeContext.highValue];
    }

    onZipCodeFilterChanged(event) {
        const zipFilter = this.possibleFilters.find(filter => filter.name === ApplicantComponent.CITY_WITH_ZIP_CODE);
        zipFilter.selection = [event.target.value];
    }

    possibleFiltersHaveAgeFilter(): boolean {
        return this.possibleFilters.find(filter => filter.name === ApplicantComponent.AGE_REQUEST) !== undefined;
    }

    possibleFiltersHaveCityRadius(): boolean {
        return this.possibleFilters.find(filter => filter.name === ApplicantComponent.CITY_WITH_RADIUS) !== undefined;
    }

    possibleFiltersHaveCityWithZipCode(): boolean {
        return this.possibleFilters.find(filter => filter.name === ApplicantComponent.CITY_WITH_ZIP_CODE) !== undefined;
    }

    private isSkillIncludeSearchActive(): boolean {
        return this.skillsIncludeFilterValues.length > 0;
    }

    private isSkillsExcludeSearchActive() {
        return this.skillsExcludeFilterValues.length > 0;
    }

    // noinspection DuplicatedCode
    private initLocationSubscription() {
        const jobLocation = this.cityForm.get('mobility').get('city');

        jobLocation.valueChanges.pipe(
            tap(() => {
                this.selectedCity = null;
                this.highlightedCity = null;
                this.proposalsVisible = false;
            }),
            debounce(() => timer(300)),
            switchMap(value => {
                // only show results if user typed something
                if (value.length > 0) {
                    return this.applicantService.findCitiesByNameOrZip(value);
                }
                return of([] as CityGeo[]);
            }),
            tap(proposals => {
                // automatically select city if it's the only option
                if (proposals.length === 1 && proposals[0].city === jobLocation.value) {
                    this.selectedCity = proposals[0];
                    return;
                }
                // mark first proposal as highlighted
                if (proposals.length > 0) {
                    this.highlightedCity = proposals[0];
                    this.proposalsVisible = true;
                }
            })
        ).subscribe(proposals => {
            this.cityProposals = proposals;
        });
    }

    private createForm() {
        this.cityForm = this.fb.group({
            mobility: this.fb.group({
                city: '',
                cityGeoId: '', // bleibt fuer den Post enthalten
                jobLocationRadius: '',
                zipCode: ''
            })
        });
    }


    // noinspection JSMethodCanBeStatic
    private isNotABooleanFilter(filter) {
        return filter.name !== ApplicantComponent.ONLY_MY_APPLICANTS &&
            filter.name !== ApplicantComponent.ONLY_MY_BRANCH &&
            filter.name !== ApplicantComponent.ONLY_MY_TENANT &&
            filter.name !== ApplicantComponent.IS_GLOBE &&
            filter.name !== ApplicantComponent.IS_MOBILE &&
            filter.name !== ApplicantComponent.IS_JOB_APPLICATION &&
            filter.name !== ApplicantComponent.IS_SPECULATIVE_APPLICATION &&
            filter.name !== ApplicantComponent.IS_APPLICANT &&
            filter.name !== ApplicantComponent.IS_SHIFTWORK_IMAGINABLE &&
            filter.name !== ApplicantComponent.IS_EMPLOYEE;
    }

    private setSelectionForAllBooleanFilter() {
        this.setSelectionForBooleanFilter(ApplicantComponent.ONLY_MY_APPLICANTS, this.onlyMyApplicants);
        this.setSelectionForBooleanFilter(ApplicantComponent.ONLY_MY_TENANT, this.onlyMyTenant);
        this.setSelectionForBooleanFilter(ApplicantComponent.ONLY_MY_BRANCH, this.onlyMyBranch);
        this.setSelectionForBooleanFilter(ApplicantComponent.IS_MOBILE, this.isMobile);
        this.setSelectionForBooleanFilter(ApplicantComponent.IS_GLOBE, this.isGlobe);
        this.setSelectionForBooleanFilter(ApplicantComponent.IS_SPECULATIVE_APPLICATION, this.speculativeApp);
        this.setSelectionForBooleanFilter(ApplicantComponent.IS_APPLICANT, this.isApplicant);
        this.setSelectionForBooleanFilter(ApplicantComponent.IS_EMPLOYEE, this.isEmployee);
        this.setSelectionForBooleanFilter(ApplicantComponent.IS_JOB_APPLICATION, this.jobApplication);
        this.setSelectionForBooleanFilter(ApplicantComponent.IS_SHIFTWORK_IMAGINABLE, this.isShiftWorkImaginable);
    }

    private setSelectionForBooleanFilter(filterName: string, isActive: boolean) {
        this.searchObject.requestFilters.filter(filter => filter.name === filterName)
            .forEach(filter => filter.selection = String(isActive));
    }

    private fetchPossibleFilters() {
        const searchPossibleFilters: ApplicantSearch = {
            pageRequest: {
                pageNum: 0,
                pageSize: 1
            }
        };

        this.isLoading = true;

        this.applicantService.searchApplicants(searchPossibleFilters).pipe(
            finalize(() => this.isLoading = false)
        ).subscribe(response => {
            this.possibleFilters = response.possibleFilters;

            const nationalityFilter = this.possibleFilters.find(filter => filter.name === 'nationality');

            if (nationalityFilter) {
                this.possibleFilters.push({
                    name: 'excludeNationality',
                    selection: undefined,
                    values: nationalityFilter.values
                });
            }

            if (!this.possibleFiltersHaveAgeFilter()) {
                this.possibleFilters.push({
                    name: ApplicantComponent.AGE_REQUEST,
                    selection: undefined,
                    values: undefined
                });
            }
            if (!this.possibleFiltersHaveCityRadius()) {
                this.possibleFilters.push({
                    name: ApplicantComponent.CITY_WITH_RADIUS,
                    selection: undefined,
                    values: undefined
                });
            }
            if (!this.possibleFiltersHaveCityWithZipCode()) {
                this.possibleFilters.push({
                    name: ApplicantComponent.CITY_WITH_ZIP_CODE,
                    selection: undefined,
                    values: undefined
                });
            }
        });
    }

    private isLanguageSearchActive() {
        return this.selectedLanguages.length > 0;
    }
}
```

Here is the payload i'm sending to the server:

```
{"pageRequest":{"pageNum":0,"pageSize":16,"sortByList":[{"name":"firstContactReceived","direction":"DESCENDING"}]},"requestFilters":[{"name":"status","values":["NEW"]}]}
```

and this is an example response:

```
{,…}
page: {content: [{id: "4381eac1-01a9-44d0-a4c2-c8df3c54e615", firstName: null, lastName: null,…},…],…}
content: [{id: "4381eac1-01a9-44d0-a4c2-c8df3c54e615", firstName: null, lastName: null,…},…]
0: {id: "4381eac1-01a9-44d0-a4c2-c8df3c54e615", firstName: null, lastName: null,…}
age: null
anonymous: true
applicantStatus: "APPLICANT"
availableFrom: "2019-10-28"
bestMatch: 75
city: "Silz, Pfalz"
contractType: "Festanstellung"
email: null
firstContactReceived: "2019-10-28"
firstName: null
id: "4381eac1-01a9-44d0-a4c2-c8df3c54e615"
isFromMyBranch: false
isFromMyTenant: false
isGlobe: false
isJobApplication: true
isMobile: true
isOwnApplicant: true
isPossibleDuplicate: true
isShiftWorkImaginable: true
isSpeculativeApplication: false
languages: []
lastName: null
nationality: null
phoneNumber: null
profession: "Kaufmann / Kauffrau für Spedition und Logistikdienstleistung"
profileCompleteness: 22
reservations: []
skills: ["Prüfplan"]
0: "Prüfplan"
status: "NEW"
tenantId: "57ce8d3e-7fb1-4efc-8e83-66148508e22c"
twentyFourHourWarning: false
vehicle: "CAR"
zipCode: ""
1: {id: "4dbcefba-f69a-416b-9ada-5ba2adf24824", firstName: "John", lastName: "Macintosh",…}
2: {id: "288923f5-17dd-4d8a-96a3-5756ec1d6a1b", firstName: "John", lastName: "MacintoshderZweite",…}
3: {id: "13c578d4-37c2-4275-89f6-e33ace8181af", firstName: "Gerti", lastName: "Müller",…}
4: {id: "e7af4b2d-35c4-4e9d-b30c-e151333e0fed", firstName: "Gertrude", lastName: "Müller",…}
5: {id: "350db96d-44ed-4ceb-84c7-2b6ef495fb81", firstName: "Lisa", lastName: "Schubert",…}
6: {id: "bc8412dd-f4dc-4a93-852d-8448c2da2ce8", firstName: "Snooze", lastName: "Light",…}
7: {id: "ced250ca-d346-4227-ab7b-f9b2fa8a012d", firstName: "Michael", lastName: "Zimmermann",…}
8: {id: "e3c55e9e-c916-4199-bdaa-a01a15e07813", firstName: "Moritz", lastName: "Zimmermann",…}
9: {id: "f8618617-f757-4161-b715-ed61631abfa9", firstName: "Mina", lastName: "Kreuzer",…}
10: {id: "df0650c9-aaf5-4630-9924-2a25224683d7", firstName: "Theo", lastName: "Dor",…}
.....
15: {id: "eae55a93-727e-47cb-8dfd-074c92bdbc48", firstName: "Jan", lastName: "Janssen",…}
totalCount: 61
possibleFilters: [{name: "profession",…}, {name: "onlyMyApplicants", values: ["false", "true"]},…]
requestedFilters: [{name: "status", values: ["NEW"]}]
```

The `pageSize` will always be at 16.

Comment: So the issue is that the `event.page` is always 1 so the `pageNum` is 1? Can you create a quick stackblitz so we can play with it?

Comment: Can you add the content of the searchApplicants method in the Applicant component please? It could be related to that.

Comment: @DavidG. i made the edit

Comment: So in the pageChange event listener you are making a request to the server and you are changing the data that is being paginated. Are the pageSize and the totalCount attributes you are passing through to the paginator going to be the same?

Comment: @DavidG. The `totalCount` will always be the same and the `pageSize` also stays at the same amount of 16 entries.

Comment: Upvoted. It has been 1 year and I am facing the same issue. Did you manage to solve it?